# Top menu Bootstrap centered (SmartAdmin Template)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble centering the top menu of a template, someone could give me a hint of what I do?

The template: http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.8.x/ajax/index.html#ajax/dashboard.html
(Need to change the config in right icon to top menu)

[Image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK2uA.png)

I tried to change `float: left` without success, `text-align` in '`li`' without success...

Thanks.

Comment: Use pic to describe what you are trying to do and a brief explanation what have you tried and the error you found so people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have no access to your code to be sure, but try to add that to your css

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
> li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
}
```

it should work, but let me know